# In ABL Web App project, which files should be tracked in a source control?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

So we're just starting with a new ABL web app with 11.6 in developer studio.

For now all files in the project structure have been added to the repository. We're already ignoring all rcode, but I wonder what else can be left aside.

Our current project has the following folders:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Progress temp-files (-T startup parameter) are outside of the project folder. Ignore crash post mortem files (procore* and protrace*).

Include .project, .propath and typically I'd include .dbconnection as well - assuming the team uses identical DB connection names here.

Everything else should IMHO be under SCM.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure libraries don't need to be in source control. PASOE Content is created along with the project, so you only need to save the files you change. And obviously any folders where you create source code should be in source control, so save the Src folder and subfolders.